# Insert HTML after nth div, after divs are re-ordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a series of divs that get loaded in with PHP. They are reordered on load in jQuery and can be re-ordered with buttons. I want to insert some HTML after the nth div (ex: always after 2nd, no matter the order). I tried:

```
$('#card-box').children(':eq(1)').after('<b>test</b>');
```

Right under the lines where the divs get reordered. But it puts it under the div that is 2nd in PHP, BEFORE they get re-ordered by jQuery, and after sorting with a button it moves to the top.

The divs are reodered in jQuery by their data-id attribute. Like so:

```
var div = $('#card-box');
var listitems = div.children('div.card').get();
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (+$(a).attr('data-id') > +$(b).attr('data-id')) ? -1 : (+$(a).attr('data-id') < +$(b).attr('data-id')) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by reordered? visually using css position or the real order on the dom tree?

Comment: @FaresM. reordered on the dom in jquery like: `var div = $('#card-box');
        var listitems = div.children('div.card').get();
        listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (+$(a).attr('data-id') > +$(b).attr('data-id')) ? -1 : (+$(a).attr('data-id') < +$(b).attr('data-id')) ?  1 : 0;
        });`

Comment: I know in jQuery. Can you post some relevent code of your sort function?

Comment: Edit your post to add this code inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-inject them into the DOM after sorting

```
var div = $('#card-box'),
    listitems = div.children('div.card');

listitems.sort(function (a, b) {....
});

listitems.detach().appendTo(div);
div.children(':eq(1)').after('<b>test</b>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n39b6sLy/)

Comment: This did not work. I already have a working line to update the dom: `$.each(listitems, function (idx, itm) { div.append(itm); }); ` My trouble is inserting html in-between the divs

Comment: You need to detach and reinject the whole sorted element not by inserting one by one. Look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n39b6sLy/) I posted it works.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to remove the `.get();` after listitems. it works now!

Comment: Great, you can upvote if you find the answer helpful.